# Last element of an array in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I know if the current iteration is the last one?

```
<th:block th:each="err: ${#fields.errors('confirmedPassword')}">
    [[${err}]], 
</th:block>
```

As you can see, a comma will be placed after each error message. However, I would like to place a full stop after the last iteration instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<th:block th:each="errMsg, errStatus: ${#fields.errors('confirmedPassword')}">
    <th:block th:text="!${errStatus.last} ? ${errMsg} + ', ' : ${errMsg} + '.'"></th:block>
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [iteration status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) variable for this.  It has a property `last` that is set to true on the last iteration.  Something like this should work:

```
<th:block th:each="err, status: ${#fields.errors('confirmedPassword')}">
  [[${err}]][# th:unless="${status.last}"],[/] 
</th:block>
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort but unfortunately the example doesn't work. But the link you have posted was very helpful. I'm going to post the correct code in a minute.